# Open Checkbox multiple tabs on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am an absolute beginner when it comes to anything JavaScript or JQuery. I am trying to get a few checkboxes open in a new tab if they are checked and then the submit button clicked. The code I have works only if one checkbox is checked. If more than one is checked, then only the first one is open in the tab. My code is as follows:

Javascript

```
function CheckCheckboxes(form)
{
var
    i, counter = 0;

for (i = 0; i < form.elements.length; ++i) {
    if ('checkbox' === form.elements[i].type && form.elements[i].checked) {++counter;
        window.open('http://' + form.elements[i].value, '_blank');
    }
}
if (!counter) {
    alert('Please check at least one!');
}
}
```

HTML

```
<form onsubmit="CheckCheckboxes(this); return false;">
<table align="left" border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;">

<tr style="height:30px">
    <td colspan="8"><center>Companies</center></td>
</tr>

<tr>
     <td><input type="checkbox" name="Google" value="www.google.com" />Google</td>
     <td><input type="checkbox" name="Apple" value="www.apple.com" />Apple</td>
     <td><input type="checkbox" name="Microsoft" value="www.Microsoft.com" />Microsoft</td>
     <td><input type="checkbox" name="facebook" value="www.facebook.com" />Facebook</td>

 <td><br /><input type="submit" value="Send Form" /></td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Been at this for 3 and a half hours :)

Thanks

Comment: your code works fine on firefox, http://jsbin.com/maloveqe/1/edit

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working but the browser is blocking the new windows after the first one is displayed. By default browsers are blocking multiple pop-ups from a website, you can turn this off though but don't expect your users to do the same.

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLUQ7/)

Your code `window.open('http://' + form.elements[i].value, '_blank');` works :)

[image]